# Extracting Keyboard Firmware

Tags: jtag

I am trying to find out how to extract firmware from a Bluetooth keyboard, my understanding is that I would have to JTAG to retrieve the the firmware from the device is that correct? Also has anyone successfully done this in the past that might be able to give me any advice, I want to review to firmware to see how the keyboard interacts with the Bluetooth stack.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

JTAG is one way, if you manage to find it on the board and figure out how to dump the firmware over it. However, there are often easier ways, e.g.

- if the firmware is in a separate flash chip, dump it instead (sometimes it's even possible [without desoldering](https://www.flashrom.org/ISP))
- if the manufacturer provides firmware updates, extract the firmware from the updater.